# Recommended way to check if a sequence is empty

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

A method returns a sequence, `IEnumerable<T>`, and you now want to check if it is empty. How do you recommend doing that? I'm looking for both good readability and good performance.

The first and most obvious way is to check that the count is greater than zero:

```
if(sequence.Count() == 0)
```

Has decent readability, but terrible performance since it has to actually go through the whole sequence.

A method that I sometimes use is the following:

```
if(!sequence.Any())
```

This doesn't (as far as I know) have to go through the whole sequence, but the readability is a bit backwards and awkward. (Reads a lot better if we are checking that the sequence is *not* empty though).

Another option is to use `First` in a try-catch, like this:

```
try
{
    sequence.First();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Not a very pretty solution, and probably slower too, since it is using exceptions and stuff. Could prevent that by using `FirstOrDefault` of course, except you would have a big problem if the first item in the sequence actually *was* the default value ;)

So, any other ways to check if a sequence is empty? Which one do you usually use? Which one do you recommend to use?

***Note:*** For optimal readability I would probably put one of the above snippets in an `IsEmpty` extension method, but I am still curious since I would have to do something inside that method as well :p

Comment: What Type is `sequence`?

Comment: @Beska: If the sequence doesn't implement `ICollection<T>`, it just iterates through. See the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx

Comment: @Neil: IEnumerable<T>. Should've noted that somewhere I suppose. Editing :)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I would use `!sequence.Any()`, personally.

If you *really* need to, you could always write your own extension method:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return !source.Any();
}
```

Then you can write:

```
if (sequence.IsEmpty())
```

Comment: +1, I created an extension method in my own app because it's easier to read "if empty" then "if not any".

Comment: +1, looking into reflector shows `sequence.Any()` as being the clear winner. Is there any reason you wouldn't want to add this extension ?..I was just wondering what the italic on "really" in emphasizing.

Comment: A nice IEnumerable<T> IsNullOrEmpty() extension method is here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/06/10/checking-for-empty-enumerations.aspx

Comment: @Dynami Le Savard: if the content of IEnumerable<T> is not yet computed (eg you're using Linq), a problem is that you may not realize that you execute things twice: calling IsEmpty will execute your Linq query, and then if it's not empty you may do a foreach and again reexecute your query.

Comment: @TimLewis probably because it wouldn't really add any value at all, it'd just make the API larger and thus harder to grasp. you'de see SO-questions asking about the performace differences between Any and IsEmpty and discussions about which is more readable and so on. if you personally feel that Any (or !Any which literally reads as "not any" which is pretty easy to understand for me) is too hard to understand, you can roll your own wrapper method.

Comment: I think `Empty` or `None` reads better in the spirit of LINQ. The verb `Is` doesnt sound functional enough :)

Comment: @nawfal: I disagree - both `Empty` and `None` sound like methods that *produce* empty sequences. Like the existing `Enumerable.Empty` method, for example.

Comment: @jon makes sense. I never liked the naming Single, which implies if count ==1 to me, though it is about getting a single item in it.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an Extension method, with this implementation.

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
        using (var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            return !enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hm, I suppose that is maybe what the Any method really does under the covers?

Comment: You should dispose the enumerator.

Comment: FYI for future readers: mt_serg's comment was based on the original version of this answer; Manish fixed that by changing to `using`, which handles the dispose for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well all these methods you're calling are LINQ extension methods, so it depends how the LINQ provider was implemented.  If you want to know if a sequence is empty, either `Count() == 0` or `Any() == false` is appropriate.  I prefer `Any()` myself.

However, depending on what actual Type your `sequence` is, you might not need to use a LINQ extension method.  I.e. if it's an array you can call `sequence.Length`.  If it's a collection, you can use `sequence.Count`.

Comment: I don't feel it is good advice to recommend `Count() == 0` vs `Any() == false` as being on equal footing, given that it is known that for some `IEnumerables` `Count` is much more expensive. Surely `Any` is the safer, and therefore superior, choice?

Comment: I prefer `Any()`, although in practice I'm pretty sure some types still have to do a count internally to return that result. Besides, `Any()` describes the intent of the code better, which I why I recommend it over `Count()`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension methods to detect if the sequence is null or does not have any item and alternatively to detect if the sequence does have at least one item, much like the `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` method.

```
 public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
     if (source == null) {
        return true;
     }

     return !source.Any();
 }

 public static bool IsNotNullOrEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
     return !source.IsNullOrEmpty();
 }
 .
 .
 .
 if (!sequence.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
     //Do Something with the sequence...
 }
```

Comment: FWIW, for the second method, I suggest the name "HasItems" - shorter and more readable than the double-negative "IsNotNullOrEmpty".

Comment: Oops. I downvoted this when I saw you calling a method on a value that might be null, but that was my mistake, given that this is an *extension* method, so is still invoked as a static method, despite the "." syntax. Sorry, too late for me to remove my downvote unless the answer is edited. I don't understand why SO doesn't allow removal of downvotes in this case. :(

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> `if(sequence.Count() == 0)`
>   Has decent readability, but terrible performance since it has to actually go through the whole sequence.

Is that actually true? You are talking about dealing with an *Interface*, `IEnumerable<T>`, and yet you are making assumptions regarding its implementation which may or may not be true. In fact, many of the custom collections I've written over the years keep a private variable that stores the current count internally, which means that returning `.Count` is a trivial matter that does not require iterating the entire collection.

So with that said, unless you know that a specific implementation is poorly optimized for `.Count`, I would use `.Count`. Avoid premature optimization wherever possible, and stick with readability.

Comment: As you say - you're dealing with an interface which does not specify how the count is calculated, so you have to assume that it could be an O(n) operation. How is it premature optimisation to use `Any` instead of `Count`? Using a method which is **designed exactly for this purpose** and **guarantees O(1) time** is not premature optimisation, it's simply not being lax.

Comment: Hm, yeah, exactly. Since I in general have no idea what kind of collection it is, I prefer to be on the safe side. As long as the safe side is not an extremely complicated one. And in this case it isn't. If you do however know that it is a list or an array for instance, I would agree that using the `Count` or `Length` can be a good option. Although I might still choose to stick to the `IsEmpty` extension method for consistency :)

Comment: Count will check to see if the sequence it's working with is really an array, and if so will return Length. Likewise, it will check for ICollection, and return Count. But the sequence could just as easily be an infinite sequence generated by an iterator expression, in which case you're going to wait an awfully long time just to find out whether the sequence is empty or not. Any() is far more reliable when you don't know the underlying sequence type.

Comment: And if you're using .NET 2.0? I kind of enjoy reminding people of these little "old fashioned" artifacts from earlier versions of the framework b/c sometimes people forget that not everybody has the ability to use the latest and greatest.

Comment: For the sake of future readers, I will point out that the extension method IEnumerable<T>.Count will check to see if the source is also an ICollection<T> or ICollection. If it is, then Count will be called on this interface. Otherwise the extension method does enumerate the entire collection to count items.

Answer (score 0):

> A method that I sometimes use is the following:
>
> ```
> if(!sequence.Any())
> ```
>
> <sup>❶</sup> This doesn't (as far as I know) have to go through the whole sequence,
>   <sup>❷</sup> but the readability is a bit backwards and awkward. (Reads a lot
>   better if we are checking that the sequence is not empty though).

1. According to Microsoft, [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) does indeed *not* have to go through the whole sequence. Quoting from the section **Remarks**:

> The enumeration of `source` is stopped as soon as the result can be
>   determined.

2. This is particularly true when testing for the presence of elements in an `if-else` statement. Arguably, readability is best if one tests for the presence of elements in the `if` statement, and the absence of elements in the `else`, thereby avoiding the use of the `!` operator:

   ```
   if (sequence.Any())
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
   ```

   Most would consider that more readable than:

   ```
   if (!sequence.Any())
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
   ```