# Do I need to consider disposing of any IEnumerable<T> I use?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, dispose

It's recently been pointed out to me that various Linq extension methods (such as `Where`, `Select`, etc) return an `IEnumerable<T>` that also happens to be `IDisposable`. The following evaluates to `True`

```
new int[2] {0,1}.Select(x => x*2) is IDisposable
```

Do I need to dispose of the results of a `Where` expression?

Whenever I call a method returning `IEnumerable<T>`, am I (potentially) accepting responsibility for calling dispose when I've finished with it?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, you don't need to worry about this.

The fact that they return an `IDisposable` implementation is an implementation detail - it's because iterator blocks in the Microsoft implementation of the C# compiler happen to create a *single* type which implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`. The latter extends `IDisposable`, which is why you're seeing it.

Sample code to demonstrate this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        IEnumerable<int> foo = Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(foo is IDisposable); // Prints True
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Note that you *do* need to take note of the fact that `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`. So any time you iterate explicitly, you should dispose of it properly. For example, if you want to iterate over something and be sure that you'll always have *a* value, you might use something like:

```
using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        throw // some kind of exception;
    }
    var value = enumerator.Current;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Do something with value and enumerator.Current
    }
}
```

(A `foreach` loop will do this automatically, of course.)

Comment: So provided I don't use the enumerator explicitly, I never need to dispose?

Comment: It's interesting to note that calling `Dispose` on an interator which has had `GetEnumerator()` called at least once will invalidate the enumerator returned by the first call, but not any enumerators returned by subsequent calls; calling `Dispose` before the first `GetEnumerator()` call has no effect.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you happen to have any insight into the odd behavior described by `supercat`?

Comment: @ean5533: The first call to `GetEnumerator()` returns a reference to the same reference; thereafter, it will create separate copies. The idea is to only create a single object in the common case of iterating exactly once.

Comment: Instead of checking true on Enumerator.MoveNext(), use Enumerator.FirstOrDefault() != null. This encapsulates disposing if required to the framework. Which is safe when working with multithreading aware collections.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce: Which Enumerator class is that? And what if the sequence is of a non-nullable value type? Or if it is a sequence with a first value of null?

Comment: If I use the nongereric version do I need to dispose? @JonSkeet

Comment: @regisbsb: The nongeneric version of what? `IEnumerable`? You *should*, IMO - `foreach` will do that automatically for you, for example.

Comment: `IEnumerator`. So I need to check if the result of `GetEnumerator()` from `IEnumerable` is `IDisposable` then if it is `Dispose` it?

Comment: @regisbsb: I would view that as a best practice, yes.