# Null reference exception after checking for null (checking for null doesn't work)

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, nullreferenceexception

Take a look at this code:

```
var categories = tokens.SelectMany(x => x.Categories);

if (categories != null)
{
    if (categories.Contains("interp")) //null ref exception
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get Null Reference Exception when I try fo find "interp" string within categories. So it seems that "categories != null" doesn't work.

I found some suggestions (here [How to check if IEnumerable is null or empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047349/how-to-check-if-ienumerable-is-null-or-empty)) but they involve using .Any(). But it only makes the exception accure earlier (while using .Any()). Even ?.Any() throws the exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check `tokens != null` if `tokens` is not `null`, `SelectMany` will never return `null` but empty enumerable

Comment: Maybe an element of `tokens` is `null`. `x.Categories` would then throw an exception when you call `Contains`.

Comment: Null checks work. If you get an NRE it means something else failed. Post the *full* exception text, including the call stack. Perhaps it was a *different* line that threw, or `Enumerable.Contains` threw because `categories` is empty. Or perhaps `x.Categories` actually contained `null` entries that ended up in the `categories` variable.

Comment: `categories != null` checks the `categories` enumerable, not its contents. If there's any chance that `x.Categories` contains nulls you should include a `Where(category=>category !=null)`

Comment: What type is your selectmany returning?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If `tokens == null`, `SelectMany` should throw an `ArgumentNullException` though. Am I missing something?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. What is the type of `categories`?

Comment: Run to this line of code `if (categories.Contains("interp"))`. When you hit it, please go to the `Immediate Window` and type in `?categories`. What is returned? What about for `?categories.Count()`? What about for `?categories.GetType()`?

Comment: @Peter82 this question should be closed either as unclear or a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). There's no way to reproduce what the question claims - an emtpy Enumerable doesn't throw. Comparison to null isn't broken, millions of developers would have noticed if it was. You need to post a *reproducible* example and the *full* exception text, including the call stack. You can get that easily with a simple `Exception.ToString()`.

Answer (score 5):

This code will throw an NRE in `categories.Contains` only if the Categories *property* is null.

The following code will throw :

```
class Token
{
    public string[] Categories{get;set;}
}

var tokens=new []{new Token()};
var categories = tokens.SelectMany(x => x.Categories);
if (categories != null)
{
    if (categories.Contains("interp")) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found");
    }
}
```

But so would

```
tokens.SelectMany(x => x.Categories).ToArray();
```

The thing that actually throws is the nested iterator *inside SelectMany*, not `ToArray()` or `Contains`. The stack trace for that exception is :

```
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at UserQuery.Main()
```

`SelectMany` will try to iterate over each `Categories` entry, find that the property is actually null and throw.

The quick fix is to add a `Where` before `SelectMany` to eliminate null Categories :

```
var categories = tokens.Where(x=>x.Categories!=null).SelectMany(x => x.Categories);
```

The *real* solution is to ensure `Categories` is never empty - it should be initialized to an empty array, list, whatever upon construction. When reassigned, it should never be set to null.

This example sets the `_categories` field to `new string[0]` even if a caller passes `null` to Categories

```
class Token
{
    string[] _categories=new string[0];
    public string[] Categories{
        get => _categories;
        set => _categories = value??new string[0];
    }

}
```

With that, `Where(x=>x.Categories !=null)` is no longer necessary

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to have got it right. `tokens` can never be null if `SelectMany` doesn't throw an exception. Upvote!

Answer (score 3):

When working with *collections* and `IEnumerable<T>` avoid using `null`; if you have nothing to return, return an *empty collection* (not `null`).

In your particular case `SelectMany` will never return `null`, but empty collection, that's why `categories != null` check is *useless*,
and you have to check `tokens` instead

```
if (null != tokens)
  // Where(x => x != null) - to be on the safe side if x == null or x.Categories == null
  if (tokens
       .Where(x => x != null && x.Categories != null)
       .SelectMany(x => x.Categories)
       .Contains("interp"))
    return null;
```

However, constant checking for `null` makes code being *unreadable*, that's why try check for `null` *once*:

```
// if tokens is null change it for an empty collection
tokens = tokens ?? new MyToken[0];

...

if (tokens 
      .Where(x => x != null && x.Categories != null)
      .SelectMany(x => x.Categories)
      .Contains("interp"))
    return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

var categories = tokens.SelectMany(x => x.Categories).ToList();

add .ToList() and you should know more about where the error is
with that information we have in the post, we can only guess

Comment: `ToList();` - try avoiding *materialization* when you don't have to do it; imaging that `tokens.SelectMany` usually returns *millions* of items (what a huge list we create for nothing since `Contains` doesn't want it)

Answer (score 0):

Can use `where` clause and make it as list , then just check if there is any element in the list

```
 var categories = list.Where(x => x.Categories.Contains("interp")).ToList();
 if (categories.Count() == 0)
  {
     return null;

   }
```