# IEnumerable check if empty in system.collection

Tags: c#, .net-core

** I have function that get an object as a parameter then trying to cast it as IEnumrable and check if it’s empty or at least have value
Is there any better way to do that than the below**

```
Private bool empty(Object obj)
{
    Bool empty=true;
    If (obj is IEnumerable lst)
    {
        foreach (var item in IEnumerable lst)
        {
        empty=false;
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: use `System.Linq` and use the extension `.Any()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if IEnumerable is null or empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047349/how-to-check-if-ienumerable-is-null-or-empty)

Comment: I think it might be better to explain why you are in this situation, and what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0).

Note. Normally you want to avoid `IEnumerable` and it's better to use `IEnumerable<T>`.