# How to know if an IEnumerable<ValueType> is empty, without counting all?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Without counting all the elements in an `IEnumerables<T>` collection of `struct` elements, what is the best way to detect if it is empty?

For example, on `class` elements I would normally test with first or default:

```
myEnumerableReferenceTypeElements.FirstOrDefault() == null
```

because null is not normally a valid value in collections being iterated.

However, in the case of value types where all values must be in a predefined range, the default value  (e.g. int default of 0) is also a viable item in the collection.

```
myValueTypeInt32Elements.FirstOrDefault() == 0   // can't tell if empty for sure
```

Comment: You should use `Any` regardless of the underlying type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Recommended way to check if a sequence is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094729/c-recommended-way-to-check-if-a-sequence-is-empty)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

```
bool isEmpty = !myEnumerable.Any();
```

From MSDN

> Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

Comment: You were first on the draw. So simple in the end. Thanks.

Comment: @John K No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

The [`.Any()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) was designed for this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isEmpty = !myEnumerableReferenceTypeElements.Any();
```